# Laravel Panel Upload Image

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm new to Laravel.
So now I'm following the docs from Laravel panel about [cruds fields](http://laravelpanel.com/docs/master/crud-fields)
, and I successfully created it with no error, now all I wanna ask is how to upload image from my controller ('objekController'), because Laravel panel doesn't create a view for my new CRUDS.

Here's my code to perform CRUDS (Im using Laravel 5.3)

```
public function  edit($entity){

    parent::edit($entity);

    $this->edit = \DataEdit::source(new \App\objek);

    $this->edit->add('nama', 'Nama', 'text')->rule('required');
    $this->edit->add('deskripsi', 'Deskripsi', 'text')->rule('required');

    //upload photo and save path
    $this->edit->add('foto', 'URL Foto', 'text')->rule('required');
    $this->edit->add('latitude', 'Latitude', 'text')->rule('required');
    $this->edit->add('longitude', 'Longitude', 'text')->rule('required');

    $this->edit->saved(function () use ($entity) {
        $this->edit->message(\Lang::get('panel::fields.dataSavedSuccessfull'));
        $this->edit->link('panel/Permission/all', \Lang::get('panel::fields.back'));
    });

    return $this->returnEditView();
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure your question is too broad. If you're new to Laravel I would suggest against using such packages, and would much rather advise you to start with the basics step by step. Make your own Image uploading panel and then use others.

Comment: can you suggest me which package i should be using for this function (image upload)? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after hours of coding, i finally realized that i didn't read the docs that laravel panel provided [here](http://laravelpanel.com/docs/master/crud-fields)
the code must be like this for image upload :

```
$this->edit->add('foto', 'URL Foto', 'file')->rule('required|mimes:jpg,jpeg,gif,png')->move('img/');
```

case closed now! :)